# In Rails, correctly refer to another method to apply change on existing data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to add slugs to my users, and cannot use friendly_id gem due to how it affects users being brought in from the CMS, and running into issues applying the slug.

So in my user table I have the following:

```
create_table "users", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
t.string "first_name"
t.string "last_name"
t.text "bio"
t.string "title"
t.string "avatar_file_name"
t.string "avatar_content_type"
t.integer "avatar_file_size"
t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
t.string "slug"
end
```

In the application model

```
def to_slug(string)
 string.parameterize.truncate(80, omission: '')
end
```

In the user model

```
def set_url_name
  self.full_name = [first_name, last_name].join('-')
end

def self.add_slugs
  update(url_name: to_slug(set_url_name))
end

def to_param
  slug
end
```

My thought was since the first_name and last_name are separate fields I should combine them with a dash for setting the url_name. So when I get into my rails console I try to apply this to existing data doing:

```
User.add_slugs
```

I end up getting

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `set_url_name''
Did you mean?  sti_name
from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activerecord-5.1.4/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
```

My first inclination is that my set_url_name method isn't pulling in correctly so I tried:

```
def self.add_slugs
 update(slug: to_slug(name))
end
```

Which results in:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_slug' for #<Class:0x007fc624e376e0>
Did you mean?  to_s
```

I've also changed out name with :first_name, first_name, :last_name, and last_name. All with the same issue. Any guidance?

Comment: you are mixing class and instance methods together hence the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `set_url_name` is an instance method, while `self.add_slugs` is a class method. Inside the `self.add_class` method, `self` refers to the `User` class rather than an instance of a user.

What you really want is something like the following:

```
def self.add_slugs
  self.find_each do |user|
    user.update(slug: user.to_slug(user.set_url_name))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems in your code:

1. The method `update` only updates a single record.
2. The method `set_url_name` should just return the value not try setting another non-existing variable.
3. The method `to_slug` doesn't exist on the class, it is an instance level method.

This is what you want:

```
def self.to_slugs
  self.find_each do |u|
    s = [u.first_name, u.last_name].join('-').parameterize.truncate(80, omission: '')
    u.update(slug: s)
  end
end
```

You have to loop through each and call update individually because you are creating the value outside of the SQL, otherwise you could use `update_all`.